# Set EditTextPreference title dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I use this code to set the `editTextPreference` title from the input text using the `getText()` method. The problem is that when I click "ok" it doesn't change the title, but if I click on the editText` another time and click "ok", it applies the title.

```
public void handleTEST(){
    final EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("test");     
    pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){   
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            pref.setTitle(pref.getText());

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you are changing the title only in `onPreferenceClick`, not when `Preference Changed` (Ok is `clicked` in `Dialog`). So next time when you click on preference item `onPreferenceClick` is called and the title changes.

If you need to change the title when Ok `Clicked` on the dialog.You need to update the `editTextPreference` title in `OnPreferenceChangeListener`

Add a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and update the `EditTextPreference` title like this

```
 private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener onPreferenceChangeListener 
                        = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if(preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            // update the title
            preference.setTitle(stringValue);

        }
        return true;
    }
  };
```